# Sinatra Sub-Directory Views

Tags: ruby, view, sinatra

I want to be able to get Sinatra views from sub-directories of ./views (such as ./views/admin). I know you can set the views like so:

```
set :views, Proc.new { File.join(root, "templates") }
```

But how would I be able to set this for only part of the file?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but you can render a view in `views/admin` by doing this:

```
erb :"admin/report"
```

If you're asking how to automatically look in subdirectories of `views` when you call `erb :report`, I'm not sure how to do that, and I don't think you'd want to (what happens if two views in different dirs have the same name?).

Comment: It works, thanks. I have to leave off the file extension, though, it adds that automatically.

Comment: Oops--good point. I've removed the extension from the code in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is supposed to be an oversized comment. The answer provided by Alex is the correct one, but to be sure, this is a quote from [official documentation](http://sinatrarb.com/intro.html):

> One important thing to remember is that you always have to reference templates with symbols, even if they’re in a subdirectory (in this case, use: `:'subdir/template'` or `'subdir/template'.to_sym`). You must use a symbol because otherwise rendering methods will render any strings passed to them directly.