# Sinatra models access root view folder

Tags: model-view-controller, view, sinatra, models, controllers

I am stuck trying to figure out how to get my models to access the root view folder in sinatra.

**File Structure**

```
config.ru
app.rb
models/
  song.rb
views/
  song/
    song.slim
    edit_song.slim
  layout.slim
  login.slim
```

When I go to view the '/song' route via song.rb, the controller tells it to render the song.slim view. However, when I do that, it ends up looking for app/models/views/song/song.slim instead of app/views/song/song.slim which is the one I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure explicit where your views are.

> ## :views - view template directory
>
> A string specifying the directory where view templates are located. By
> default, this is assumed to be a directory named “views” within the
> application’s root directory (see the :root setting). The best way to
> specify an alternative directory name within the root of the
> application is to use a deferred value that references the :root
> setting:

## Example

```
set :views, Proc.new { File.join(root, "../views") }
```

Simply add this to your configure methode. [How?](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Configuration)

## According your Example

Shoud it be `set :views, Proc.new { File.join(root, "../views") }` from your model. And render it with `slim :"song/song"` or `slim :"song/edit_song"` [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129504/sinatra-sub-directory-views)

Not sure but if your routing logic in app.rb you can skip the part with set the view folder.

Comment: I've tried that but it doesnt work. 

I'm trying to access the views in views/songs/*.slim from the folder models/song.rb

so in my root directory i have app/models and app/views

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a better example of your folder and file structure.

Comment: ok, after a mostly good night's sleep and a refreshed mind, i tried what Sir Script added to his answer. I think before, I didnt know that i was supposed to set the view from within the model but that makes sense now. I was placing it in the main application file.